# Sephardic Halakhoth for Kashering a Sink

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, kashering-kosherization

Moving into a new place, the previous tenant was not Jewish, and the sink is made from porcelain. i know that Hacham Ovadia Yosef Zal allowed Sephardim to kasher a porcelain sink for Pesach by using boiling water, but i don't know of his (or other Sephardic) rulings involving a previously non kosher sink. Does anyone know of Ovadia's or other Sephardic Rabbi's opinions regarding this matter?